Which element to use in LTspice for this strange node label in CircuitLab?
In the Ultimate Electronics interactive online book, there is a section called Voltage-Controlled Switch.  In this section there are are 7 examples of how to use a voltage-controlled switch.
The last example (#7) states:


Finally, we can use a voltage within the circuit itself as the
trigger. This example is a bit more complicated, but it uses the fact
that the voltage-controlled switch model has hysteresis. Hysteresis
means that after the switch changes from one state to the other,
there’s some memory so that a larger wiggle is required to get it to
switch back to the first state. This is configured within the V_H
parameter of the switch SW2. Double-click SW2, try changing the
hysteresis voltage V_H, and re-run the simulation:


with a link to these interactive schematics:

Within this schematic there is a strange node label “+5V” (a “Named node” by the CircuitLab terminology) which I've circled in red. While hovering the mouse over this node, CircuitLab shows that this node's DC voltage is indeed +5 V (shown below), even though it's never connected to a voltage source elsewhere in the schematic.

When converting these schematics to LTspice, I decided to replace this "named node" with an explicit voltage source to obtain the same result (for the output voltage value in the time-domain simulation), but without success.  I got either a constant value, or the simulation simply didn't work (no window for the waveform viewer; dimmed icon for the “run simulation” symbol).  I was forced to halt the simulation with Ctrl + H.
I also tried a different connection of this voltage source (V2), for example this one:

Its netlist (without the first line):
V1 N001 0 12V
C1 out 0 22mF
R1 out 0 6Ω
R2 out N003 6Ω
SW1 N001 N003 N002 out S1
V2 N002 out 5V
.tran 5
.model S1 SW(Vh=-.75 Ron=.1 Vt=2.5)
* By https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/switches/#voltage-controlled-switch\n\n(option 7)
.backanno
.end

How can I make this work in LTspice (I use version 17.1.14)?

UPDATE:
My question is expressed in its title.  I am not interested in other solutions.  I want to substitute that strange CircuitLab label (which implies a DC voltage) with something accessible within LTspice.
Why? For any instance in the future where I encounter this same label type in some totally different circuit in CircuitLab.
Here's another thing I tried (the result of its simulation was a constant voltage, about 2.15 V for the “out” node):


UPDATE 2:
The circuit, which (almost) exactly matches the circuit in CircuitLab, is this one:

The result: no window for the waveform viewer; just a dimmed icon for the “run simulation” symbol.  I was forced to halt the simulation with Ctrl + H.
Why almost exactly?
Because:

LTspice doesn't allow zero resistance for a closed switch, so I used 0.001 Ω (1 milliohm) instead.

CircuitLab has only 3 adjustable parameters for a voltage-controlled switch (R_ON, V_T, V_H), and LTspice has an additional 4 (Roff, Lser, Vser, Ilimit). Namely, Lser (series inductance) and Vser (series voltage), both with default values of 0.0, may play some role in the result.



What difference do you see between the sims? Try to use this directive ---> .tran 0 5 0 10u uic.

@G36, you hit the nail on the head, thanks! The uic parameter was important, the .tran 5 uic was sufficient. In spite of the waveform is not exactly the same as in CircuitLab  (it begins with 0 V instead of 6 V - probably it's related to the initial state of the switch), the shapes are the same. — If you transfer your comment into an answer and explain the importance of the uic parameter, I'll accept it.

I think that is strange that in CircuitLab waveform begins at 6V. It should begins at 0V (the capacitor is initially discharge). Not an open circuit.

@G36, so the LTspice is correct in this particular simulation, and CircuitLab not.

@G36  Looks like CircuitLab puts this switch into the ON position when calculating the DC operating point for this circuit.  I don't know how it knows to do this since with the feedback it's not determinable.

@MarianD  No, not necessarily.  LTspice tries to calculate the initial operating position of the switch, but fails to do so and that's why the uic works (although startup is the better option).  CircuitLab somehow just assumes this switch is ON initially, which I don't know how it does this.  So you can't really compare the two, although I would say LTspice's behavior is more realistic.  Forcing the capacitor to an initial value is what makes this circuit work in real life.  By the way, you can also do the equivalent of uic in CircuitLab by setting the "Skip Initial" to "Yes".

@Ste Kulov, thanks for your explanation and for your very good edit of my answer.

Every time CircuitLab encounters a node with a name that implies some fixed potential, like "+5V" or "−12", beheind the scenes it inserts a voltage source to produce that potential. The following are equivalents in CircuitLab:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The name "P5" is arbitrary, Since CircuitLab interprets "+5V" as being attached to a hidden 5V source, you can't use such names for regular nodes. This can be convenient, since it permits schematics with implied voltage sources, but where none are actually shown, which might otherwise clutter up the schematic:

simulate this circuit
Using explicit voltage sources, the equivalent would be:

simulate this circuit
Notice that all the source are with respect to ground. In other words, one side is always connected to ground, otherwise terms like "+5V" and "−100V" would be meaningless.
LTspice doesn't interpret node names like this, so while you can actually use the name "+5V", it will not include any implied voltage source. You can however define those sources explicitly like I did above in one part of the schematic, and make implied connections to them elsewhere:

Your own LTspice schematic can be adapted to use the same technique:

A transient analysis usually begins with an implied .op operating point analysis, to establish starting conditions. A .op is not about stepping through time, it's about state after a long time, long enough for all capacitors to have charged to a steady voltage, and all inductors have settled to some steady current. The .op "thinking" in your case would go like this:

S1 is open. After a long time C1 will have discharged to 0V.
S1 will therefore have 0V input, causing it to close.
S1 is therefore initially closed, in fact. Try again.
S1 is closed. C1 will eventually charge to 6V.
S1 will therefore have 6V input, causing it to open.
S1 is therefore initially open, in fact. Try again from step 1

The loop never ends, and the .tran proper can never even get started.
To solve this problem, tell the .tran analysis to skip the implied .op, using the uic flag. In the above LTspice schematic, notice how the .tran directive has the uic flag, to skip calculation of initial conditions.
You will also find a checkbox in the simulation dialogue box to add the uic flag for you:

Now you should see the correct simulation results:

If you really require an operating point analysis, perhaps for simulation of other parts of the circuit, then an alternative approach would be to have the 12V source start at zero, and rise to 12V after a microsecond or so, so oscillation does not occur initially, and the .tran begins in a state where a steady state can be established. That can be done using a piecewise voltage source PWL(0 0 1u 0 2u 12):

There are probably a dozen ways you can prevent .op from failing like that, and they would all involve avoiding the situation where there exists no steady-state condition that doesn't contradict itself.

It sounds like the questioner already figured this part out. There is a conflating of two problems here, due to the specific circuit being simulated in the question. The first is what you’re addressing in this answer. The second is that CircuitLab decides the switch is ON for the operating point solution. LTspice however can’t find a stable state for the operating point due to the feedback and stalls. This 2nd discrepancy is what’s causing the confusion when translating the circuit from CircuitLab -> LTspice. I think you need to address this too for your answer to be complete.

Check the question’s comments for more info.

Thank you @SteKulov, you are absolutely correct.

@Simon Fitch, thank you for very very nice and comprehensible answer, beside the answer to my question you explained me other useful things.

Beautiful answer. Thank you!

You did not wire up the voltage source correctly. The negative terminal of the voltage source should be connected to ground, not to OUT.
Here is the circuit with the +5V node replaced by a voltage source V2, and closer to the layout of your circuits.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With the parameters for SW1 set at V_T = 2.5 and V_H = 1.5, the output looks like this:

In the edited version of the question, there is a circuit similar to this, but with the parameters for the switch set at Vt = 2.5 and Vh = -0.75.  Try changing Vh to 1.5 as in the original circuit.

"You did not wire up the voltage source correctly. " - I know about it, it was only one of my desperate trials. Your advice I already tried, too - no success.

@MarianD Then why didn't you post a schematic that matches the CircuitLab version?

"Then why didn't you post a schematic that matches the CircuitLab version?" — Because I'm not able to provide it, after all, it is the core of my question. If I know how to do it, I didn't write this question.

@MarianD. You said you tried it and it didn't work. Please post the schematic that you tried where the negative terminal of the voltage source is connected to ground instead of OUT.

Very nice from you for your effort to help me, I already thought that nobody knows the answer. I appended the schematic you demanded into my answer.

@MarianD Try changing the V_H parameter for the switch to 1.5.

"Try changing the V_H parameter for the switch to 1.5" — It was my first trial, unsuccessful (no plot, dimmed icon, I have to halt it with Ctrl+H). — Thanks for updating your answer, it seems nice (it is the expected behavior), but your plot is made in CircuitLab, whereas I want to reach the same result in LTspice.

@MarianD Once again, please post your circuit that matches the CircuitLab circuit. I don't understand why you intentionally (or was it accidentally?) posted a circuit you apparently knew did not match the CircuitLab circuit.

Sorry for my mistake (it was not the intent), now I added the appropriate circuit into my question. — Your access to my problem (simulate it for comparison in CircuitLab) was very appropriate, so I upvoted your answer, because it narrowed the reasons for the lack of success (a bug in LTspice or the influence of other parameters, not presented in CircuitLab). Thank you very much!

If you want the switch to actually "switch", then the voltage that controls it should likely be a pulse voltage source that changes voltage at some point...rather than a solid DC voltage that never changes.
In the example below, the voltage source controlling the switch starts off at zero, which means the switch is open (it is below the switch's threshold voltage of 0.5V).
Initially, the switch is open, so the TRAN does a solution as if the switch resistance is 10MEGohm...so C1 is mostly discharged. The switch is open because V1 is initially 0V.
But very shortly after zero seconds (as the transient run begins), switch S1 closes, and becomes 0.001 ohms...because V1's voltage is above threshold
Then at two seconds, voltage of source V1 falls below 1V, which is below threshold, so the switch resistance changes from .001 ohms to 10MEG in a short span of time.

Note that the switch control voltage source (here V1) is grounded. Control is isolated from the switch function. No current flows from V1. Grounding isn't necessary, but having one of V1's terminals at a solidly stable point (ground) eases my mind.

Thanks for your answer, but is is only the option 3) from the 7 options in that book, and with it, I had no problem. :-(

Without knowing what the book's seven options actually outline, it is hard to help. I have found LTspice;s HELP menu item (function key F1) useful. Searching for SW brings up clear explanations of how voltage-controlled-switches work for many different scenarios

1. "Without knowing what the book's seven options actually outline" — the link is in my question. - 2. " I have found LTspice;s HELP menu item (function key F1) useful. " — me too, long time ago. :-) - 3. "Searching for SW brings up clear explanations of how voltage-controlled-switches work for many different scenarios" - I read this part many times, long time ago your advice, too.  -- But in spite of no usefulness of your tips for me, they are all good advice, so thanks for them.
